# Missing dependency for hdf5: totem Error: Failed cloning git repository; git clome time out

Tags: git, torch, luarocks

I tried to install [torch-hdf5](https://github.com/deepmind/torch-hdf5/blob/master/doc/usage.md) by the official instruction in project page, but an missing dependency error occurred:

```
> $ luarocks make hdf5-0-0.rockspec LIBHDF5_LIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"

Missing dependencies for hdf5:
totem 

Using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/totem-0-
0.rockspec... switching to 'build' mode
Cloning into 'torch-totem'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.255.113]: errno=Operation timed out
github.com[1: 192.30.255.112]: errno=Operation timed out


Error: Failed installing dependency: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/totem-0-0.rockspec - Failed cloning git repository.
```

Actually, I can clone the totem using `git clone https://github.com/deepmind/torch-totem.git`. I wonder that there is any way to install `torch-totem` after cloning it locally, just like `luarocks make` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the dependency problem by using the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/deepmind/torch-totem.git
cd torch-totem
cp rocks/totem-0-0.rockspec ./   #copy the rockspec file in the root dirctory of project
luarock make
```

Then the message shows as below:

```
Updating manifest for xxx/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks
totem 0-0 is now built and installed in xxx/torch/install/ (license: BSD)
```